# How long to wait between shots when using a deployed designated marksman rifle?

Tags: battlefield-2, project-reality

In [Project Reality](http://www.realitymod.com/) (BF2 version) you have to wait between consecutive shots for the weapon to completely settle, even though there is (unfortunately) no visual feedback for this information.

For designated marksman rifles I know that I should wait ~2 seconds between shots in undeployed mode, but how long do I need to wait in deployed mode? I realize the answer might be different across different rifle types, I would just be happy for a rough number.

Alternatively, a link to anywhere that details the exact settle times for all weapons will also be welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2 second settle time actually is accurate for deployed mode for marksman riffles. With the benefit of higher accuracy.

Also, Full settle time for ANY weapon is not required unless you've been on the move for 5 seconds. This works linearly, so if you've been on the move for 1 second, you'll only require 1/5th of the settle time, for 2 seconds, 2//5ths etc.

Comment: I didn't quite understand - how long should I wait for max accuracy between shots if I'm perfectly stationary, then?

Comment: My understanding is the wait time between stationary shots should require very little settle time, if not none.